# Use of try-catch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, try-catch

How time-intensive is the use of `try`/`catch` in JavaScript?  I have an application and I am using it in a function which is called a few hundred times. Now I am afraid, that the `try`/`catch` statement is taking too much time and the application will take a lot longer than without it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some nice tests on jsPref:

- http://jsperf.com/try-catch-performance-overhead
- http://jsperf.com/try-catch-versus-massive-if
- http://jsperf.com/try-catch-002

**Conclusion: on the major browser, null to minimal differences.**

Comment: No difference IF the catch block is never entered. If it does it can cause huge performance issues b/c catch blocks are dynamic scope. Never use them for program logic, only for real unavoidable errors.

http://yuiblog.com/assets/High_Perf_JavaScr_Ch2.pdf

Comment: Functions containing try and catch statements are inlined if an error is not thrown, otherwise if it is the method/function is then de-optimised.

Comment: The PDF linked above now 404s but can be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20111027151214/https://yuiblog.com/assets/High_Perf_JavaScr_Ch2.pdf

Answer (score 7):

You should take note of the following:

> “The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet.” - Michael A. Jackson

I've wasted time optimising sections of code that had little impact on performance. Make sure you know what is slow by running some timing experiments.

Answer (score 2):

The `try`/`catch` clause creates a new scope in javascript, so every variable that has to come from the parent scope will be slightly slower.

The overhead isn't *that* great but too large to completely ignore for your inner loops.

Take a look at this video for a more in-depth explanation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU

Comment: It is not correct to say that a `try` block introduces new scope.

Comment: @Pointy: true, but I can't think of a better description right now. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I know what you're getting at but I'm pretty ignorant of sophisticated "language lawyer" terminology :-)

Comment: thx, nice site (especially that you can create your own test cases. The point most interesting for me was if a try-catch statement was much slower than the if statement . According to the tests it's about 25% slower. I have to see in the final application if this is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

In general, code executed inside a `try` block is expensive. But if you are invoking a `try` block on the order of a few hundred times, it's probably not an issue. If it were a few hundred thousand, you may want to re-think your design.