# Why isn't Try/Catch used more often in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It seems like with other languages that support Try/Catch, developers make use of that feature more than they do in JavaScript.  Is there a reason for this?  Is the JS implementation of Try/Catch flawed?

Comment: My guess is that people don't know about it or know how to use it.  Or, sometimes with simple checks you can avoid having to use `try`, if you can detect that it will fail before it does.

Comment: They do, but javascript is better without them really.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144326/try-catch-in-javascript-isnt-it-a-good-practice

Comment: i mean its not some high level coding that requires to check errors, you are manipulating DOM, catching events, if anything goes wrong it stops, even catching exceptions would stop

Comment: @I-love-php - remember javascript can be used in other ways too (see node.js)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try taking a look at this article: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2#trycatch

*From the above link:*

The try-catch-finally construct is fairly unique. Unlike other constructs, it **creates a new variable in the current scope at runtime**. This happens **each time** the catch clause is executed, where the caught exception object is assigned to a variable. This variable does not exist inside other parts of the script even inside the same scope. It is created at the start of the catch clause, then destroyed at the end of it.

Because this variable is created and destroyed at runtime, and represents a special case in the language, **some browsers do not handle it very efficiently**, and **placing a catch handler inside a performance critical loop may cause performance problems when exceptions are caught**.

You can also view a similar question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260526/use-of-try-catch-in-javascript)

**UPDATE**

Adding a link to: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers as it contains useful information regarding V8 and how it handles these (and similar) constructs.

In particular:

Currently not optimizable:

- Generator functions
- Functions that contain a for-of statement
- Functions that contain a try-catch statement
- Functions that contain a try-finally statement
- Functions that contain a compound let assignment
- Functions that contain a compound const assignment
- Functions that contain object literals that contain **proto**, or get
  or set declarations.

Likely never optimizable:

- Functions that contain a debugger statement
- Functions that call literally eval()
- Functions that contain a with statement

Comment: Even worse (from a performance perspective) is that V8 at least, won't optimize functions with a try-catch. So even if the entire loop happens inside the try block, it's slower. I improved performance in one test about 10-15% just by moving a performance-critical loop inside its own function, and keeping the try-catch outside of it.

Comment: Would a try-finally block without any catch have a performance penalty then?

Comment: @Nathan Looking here: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers it seems both try-catch and try-finally are not optimizable in V8. "*Some constructs are flat out not supported in the optimizing compiler and using such syntax will make the containing function unoptimizable.

It is important to note that even if the construct is unreachable or not run, these constructs still cause a function to be unoptimizable.*"

Comment: Update: according to https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers, all but the first and last of the "currently not optimizable" constructs are now optimizable.

Answer (score 15):

No it's not flawed, but for synchronous code it's typically easier and cleaner to check things with your own code than use a clunky `try{}catch(e){}`.

example:

```
var container = document.getElementById("timmy");
container.innerHTML = "I'm timmy!";
```

If there's no element whose ID is "timmy", we can handle that either like this:

```
try
{
    container.innerHTML = "I'm timmy";
}
catch (error)
{
    //handle no container
}
```

or:

```
if(container) container.innerHTML = "I'm timmy";
else //handle no container
```

---

Another thing to keep in mind is JavaScript applications are event-driven and try/catch blocks in the main part of your program can't catch errors that occur in event callbacks.

example:

```
sqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM table", 
    function(){console.log("queried!");});
```

that will trigger some native code that runs as your program continues. If an error occurs, you can't expect your program to back-track up to this line so your error handler can do its stuff! Instead, you handle errors in the call-back itself. It is common practice to provide callbacks with any error that occurred by passing it as the first parameter.

```
sqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM table", 
    function(error, data){
        if(error) console.log("query failed");
        else console.log("queried!");
    });
```

Alternatively, if your code fails in a callback, you can handle it the way I mentioned above.

```
link.onclick = function(e)
{
    var popUp = document.getElementById("popup");
    if(!popUp)
        return true; //follow link if no pop-up exists
    popUp.style.display = "block";
};
```

Comment: If, *by doing a bit of testing*, you can make sure the exception cannot happen, then no need for try catch.  There are only a handful of situations in Javascript where you have to test/probe for errors.

Answer (score 9):

The async nature of most javascript code hides the try/catch at a low level and then calls an error callback.

Most heavy code in js is async and uses a callback or promise pattern. The other code is simple and does not require try/catch.

If you dig into js libraries (pick your favorite) you will find the try/catch blocks that wrap much of the heavy app code that executes in modern js applications. These libraries then call the error or fail callback that you see in many js code samples.

Comment: I really think this is the primary reason.  Most of errors you need try/catch for are hidden deep in the bowls of various libraries. Other potential error conditions can be easily checked before attempting the operation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that there is more overhead with a try/catch as opposed to an if statement, although i think it only matter when the exception is actually thrown.  I use try/catches often, but only if I know there will be a good chance an exception could be thrown.

If used efficiently there is really no reason to not use a try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't need them much, the reason is, there is hardly any reason to catch errors, because, one error does not stop the entire script.
Javascript is event driven, most functions run when a specific event occurs, and it is client side, so if anything goes wrong, it goes wrong, catching and handling the error would be hardly any beneficial.
only my view.

Comment: Consider calling A.func(), since JavaScript is a dynamic language with runtime typechecking with late binding, we have no static guarantees that A has function func() attached to it. This can throw an error, which requires a try-catch block to mitigate. If any of your method invocations can cause an exception, you need to be catching these errors somewhere in your code. Not catching this means you have no clue what your app is doing, and in server-side code, can crash your server.

Comment: @NielsJoubert no it doesn't require try-catch, that's just a bug in your code. You don't need "static guarantees".