# How to avoid errors when manipulating unknown object/function input

Tags: javascript

When handling user input (in a JS library, not form text), it's easy to throw type-related errors, when a user supplies a non-function and you expected a function for instance. Suppose I have a function `callFn` that takes a function and arguments to supply to it and evaluates the function or returns null if it fails to, I can either use try-catch or simply check that the input is a function before calling:

```
callFn(fn, args) {
    return fn instanceof Function ? fn.apply(window, args) : null;
}
//vs
callFn(fn, args) {
    var ret = null;
    try {
        ret = fn.apply(window, args);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e) //Still display error for debugging
    }
    return ret;
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both ways? Am I correct in the following:

- Try-catch is slower, but not significantly so
- Try-catch can prevent optimization (see [In Javascript, is it expensive to use try-catch blocks even if an exception is never thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727905/in-javascript-is-it-expensive-to-use-try-catch-blocks-even-if-an-exception-is-n), not sure if this still applies, can't find anything more recent)
- Try-catch will also handle any errors in the supplied function, which can be advantageous or disadvantageous depending on context

Any the biggest one and why I'm considering switching to try-catch

- If the user supplies an object with 10+ fields and many of those fields are functions to evaluate or objects to access, a single try-catch statement will suffice if the function returns the same for any error, but the error preventing way would have to 10 - 20 `instanceof`/`typeof` statements; thus try-catch is much more readable (and faster to write).

I'm asking since I hardly ever see try-catch, and was unsure if there is a better (good) reason for it to be bad practice.

Comment: If you're writing a library you usually don't want to try-catch the errors away: if the developer is passing you rubbish or using your code wrong they should notified by errors. If you wrap things up in a try-catch there will be no errors and the code will be harder to debug.

Comment: That's the purpose of logging the error. Sometimes it's useful to have a function return without errors even with bad input (pretty much every lodash function).