# async await try catch performance issue

Tags: node.js, async-await

I wrote a Javascript code using async, await and used try, catch in each async function.

Suppose if I write 10 async function then I need to write try, catch in all those 10 functions. Now I am getting question in my mind that doesn't it cause performance overhead?

If it causes any performance overhead then what will be the solution for this problem?

Comment: You would have to show us the SPECIFIC and REAL code (not pseudo code) for us to comment.  There is no generic substitute for `try/catch` if your code needs it.  And, ALL performance questions like this ultimately need to be resolved by measuring/testing in a specific JS engine or by realizing that you're microptimizing something that you haven't even proven there is a performance issue with (also done with measuring) and not spending any time worry about it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write single try catch, in try you can add all of the async-await functions.

```js
try { 
   // service as an example
   const get = await service.get()
   const post = await service.post()
   const delete = await service.delete()
} catch(e) {
  throw new Error(e)
}
```

Comment: Whether writting try catch in each async function cause performance issue?

Comment: Try catch is same as calling callbacks like .then() and .catch() so performance is the same, just the code is sync

Comment: If you have any link or docs please provide, not able to follow.

Comment: You can read the last pharagraph of the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19728876/3756237